# get all instagram nodes from instragram URL

Tags: json, instagram

So from browsing a few stackoverflow answers I came accross this url:

`https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`

Obviously replacing `{username}` with the username - gives me a JSON string of the last 12 images posted to that user account.

Is there anyway to get more? I tried replacing `a=1` with `a=2` but that doesnt return JSON, just takes me to the instragram account.  How can I get all post images from this users history, without having to access the instagram API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

passing the `end_cursor` value to `max_id`parameter will get you next result,

Ex :

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1&max_id={end_cursor}
```

Getting Video URL:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/{post_id}/?__a=1      #this will contain the direct video url
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just another side question I've come up against, do you know how I can get the src URL for posts that are videos?